# Get the content of the file by using angular-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I create an `input` for file upload by [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) -

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" multiple />
```

I upload a sample json file -

```
{
    name: "Alice"
}
```

and I want to see its content on the `onAfterAddingFile` event -

> onAfterAddingFile function(item) {: Fires after adding a single file to the queue.

```
uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function (fileItem) {
    console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem.formData); // fileItem.formData is []
}
```

but the `fileItem.formData` just contain - `[]`

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrzfmytg/21/)

How could I get the content of the uploaded file ?

Comment: what do you want with the content of file? [`formData` is actually _Data to be sent along with the files_](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API#properties) so not sure why you are looking for that..

Comment: Ok , any other way to get the content is acceptable .

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to access content.. or you want metadata like name and modified date and all?

Comment: I want the actually content  (not the metadata) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onAfterAddingFile` - fires after adding file into upload queue. The file itself isn't uploaded yet, so you can't reach any content, just meta information. Moreover, as far as I understand, `formData {Array}: Data to be sent along with this file` means that this is complementary data to send, not file data.